# Group matching list items until change then repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to group items in a list to display them. The logic is the following.

I have a list: `list = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6]`
I want to turn this into: `grouped_list = [[1,1],[2],[3],[4,4],[5,5],[6]]`

I have tried the following:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if(list[i] == list[i+1]):
        temp_list.append(list[i])
    else:
        grouped_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list.clear()
        grouped_list.append([list[i]])
```

However, this keeps resulting in the wrong output.

Comment: Can you give an example of current output?

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your code?
What is your context to try to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> l = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6]
>>> res = [list(grp) for k, grp in itertools.groupby(l)]
>>> res
[[1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for that:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

your_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]

your_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i in your_list:
    your_dict[i].append(i)

result = sorted(your_dict.values())  # Skip this line if order doesn't matter
print(result)
# [[1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst error is the use of an unique `temp_list`. Each time you add `temp_list` to `grouped_list` it is the *same* list that you add. The `clear` method empty this unique list. Instead `temp_list.clear()` you should do `temp_list = []` to have a new list.

You should iterate only to `len() - 1` because you do an access to `i + 1`.

There are other problems, but these two are the most important.

Also, don't use `list` for a variable name, because that redefine a standard item of Python. You could that, but it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without dependencies:

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]

c = list()
for n in set(l):
    c.append( [n]*l.count(n) )
```

Result:

```
[[1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: The algorithmic complexity is awful. Iterate on the list and compare successive value is really better.

Comment: Can you post an answer?

Comment: Done.
There is an other possible problem with your solution. In general context with a list something like [1, 1, 2, 1] your code join all values 1 and do not join only consecutive values. Depending of what we want, it is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer. This does work with `[1, 1, 2, 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

An answer without use of a "special" function of the standard library. (It is to show to @Adam. I think that the answer of @abc with `itertools.groupby()` is the better answer.)

```
seq = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
print(seq)


temp_seq = []
grouped_seq = []
previous = None

for n in seq:
    if previous != n:
        previous = n
        if temp_seq:
            grouped_seq.append(temp_seq)
            temp_seq = []

    temp_seq.append(n)

if temp_seq:
    grouped_seq.append(temp_seq)


print(grouped_seq)
```

Comment: Certainly utilising libraries is usually better. Good to see other algorithms; I've improved my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension with some built-in structures (repeat, count and set) :

```
import numpy as np

lis = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6] 
grouped_list = [np.repeat(x, lis.count(x)).tolist() for x in set(lis)]
grouped_list
```

Result:

```
[[1, 1], [2], [3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
```

Hint: avoid use "list" as a name for your lists, since it is a reserved word for a Python structure. The same is valid for "dict" and "set".